# get selected tabbed panel in the flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

i have a tabbed panel in the flex having various tabs and i m using this to get the selected tab index

```
private function handleInspectorAreaButtonClick(e:Event):void
        {
            var selectedIndex:int;

            switch(Button(e.target))
            {
                case propertiesButton:
                    selectedIndex = 0;
                    break;

                case dimensionsButton:
                    selectedIndex = 1;
                    break;

                case footnotesButton:
                    selectedIndex = 2;
                    break;

                case calculationsButton:
                    selectedIndex = 3;
                    break;

                case whereUsedButton:
                    selectedIndex = 4;
                    break;
            }

            inspectorAreaViewStack.selectedIndex = selectedIndex;
        }
```

but problem is that i m not getting the selected tabbed index value m getting NULL and therefore the tab is not selected this is the panel in which m selecting

```
    <s:HGroup id="inspectorAreaViewStackControls" width="100%" paddingTop="8" paddingLeft="4" paddingRight="4">
        <s:Button id="property" label="Properties" click="handleInspectorAreaButtonClick(event)"/>
        <s:Button id="distance" label="Dimensions" click="handleInspectorAreaButtonClick(event)"/>

    </s:HGroup>
```

this is my view stack which i want to change

```
<mx:ViewStack id="inspectorAreaViewStack" width="100%" height="100%" paddingTop="8" paddingLeft="4" paddingRight="4" selectedIndex="0" backgroundColor="0xFFFFFF">

            <s:NavigatorContent width="100%" label="propertiesContent">
                <tagInspectorAspects:PropertiesAspect id="propertiesAspect"/>
            </s:NavigatorContent>

            <s:NavigatorContent width="100%" label="dimensionsContent">
                <tagInspectorAspects:DimensionsAspect/>
                    </mx:ViewStack>
```

Comment: can you post the complete code ? and also inside the switch case use case property: instead of case propertiesButton:

Comment: @rajesh.adhi i edited the code and this is all i have

Comment: Librak , which solution u found this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<s:HGroup id="inspectorAreaViewStackControls" width="100%" paddingTop="8" paddingLeft="4" paddingRight="4">
        <s:Button id="property" label="Properties" click="handleInspectorAreaButtonClick(event)"/>
        <s:Button id="distance" label="Dim" click="handleInspectorAreaButtonClick(event)"/>
</s:HGroup>


private function handleInspectorAreaButtonClick(e:Event):void
        {
            var selectedIndex:int;

            switch(e.currentTarget.id)
            {
                case 'property':
                    selectedIndex = 0;
                    break;

                case 'distance':
                    selectedIndex = 1;
                    break;
            }

            inspectorAreaViewStack.selectedIndex = selectedIndex;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the particular statement as follows

{
    event.currentTarget.selectedIndex;

}
event must be a mouse event.